# Facebook photo tagging sample code?

Tags: facebook, winforms, facebook-graph-api

I need to create a Winform which contain a button to open Facebook Photo Albums and be able to view the photos inside. Does any1 know where can l find CODING TUTORIAL or SAMPLE CODE for Facebook photo tagging? I've been googling for few days, still cannot find any step by step tutorials. Any1 who know pls help.

Comment: clarify the question. Do you want to build your own Photo tagging like Facebook or do you wish to leverage off Facebook's functionality to achieve the tagging?

Comment: I wish to open (my or not mine) Facebook Photos through Winform, and be able to tag other people.

Comment: thats easy! Drag a webbrowser control into your winform and WebBrowser.Navigate (url_with_facebook_pics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your accept rate: Simply drag a webbrowser control into your winform and type this code into the Form_Load event

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate (url_with_facebook_pics)
```